# Proving assigments in constructor's body are inefficient

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I read in http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/init-lists.html
 that using initializer lists is more efficient than doing assigment in the body of the constructor, because for example in `Fred::Fred() { x_ = whatever; }`

1) the expression whatever causes a separate, temporary object to be created, and this temporary object is passed into the x_ object's assignment operator. Then that temporary object is destructed at the ;

2)the member object will get fully constructed by its default constructor, and this might, for example, allocate some default amount of memory or open some default file

How can  assigment cause the creation of some temporary object inside the constructor? That means that the  Construtor would call itself: an infinite recursive call

I made the following piece of code to verify a copy of the object is created in the assigment process,hoping to see the additional creation and destruction of the temporary object but all I can see is the creating and destruction of the object I am creating in the main an of course no infinite recursive call.
How do I make sense of it and how can I modify the code to see the creation and destruction of the temporary object?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    private:
    int c_var;
    public:
    Base( )
    {   c_var=10;
        cout <<"Constructor called"<<endl;
        cout << "Value is " << c_var<<endl;
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout <<"Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base il;
}
```

Comment: Members not explicitly listed in the initialiser list are default-initialised. If that member is then assigned in the constructor body, it will have been both default initialised and assigned when the constructor completes. Whereas, a member that is initialised in the constructor initialiser list, and not assigned in the body, will have only been initialised. For basic types like `int`, default initialisation followed by an assignment is *at least* as costly as a single initialisation that has the same net effect.

Comment: @Peter Not to mention that types that are not default constructible or not assignable or that are used as `const` members can *only* be initialized and cannot ever be assigned in the constructor body.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - True.   The OP's example had only an `int` member, which can be both default initialised and assigned. In my comment, I didn't bother to expand on those cases where default initialisation or assignment (or both) is not possible.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ,  I agree for const members, what non-const types aren't default constructible or assignable? (apart from references)

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver many user defined types can be not default constructed nor assigned. Here's one: `struct foo { int m_i; foo(int i) : m_i(i) {} foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete; };`

Comment: @JesperJuhl The only member data is an int, the operator is a function overloading. I don't see what is type that can't be default constructed or assigned here and why

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver The *type* is `foo`. Try do default construct a `foo`. You cannot, it doesn't have a default constructor. Try to assign to an already initialized `foo`. You cannot since it doesn't have an assignment operator. So, if you use a `foo` as a member of your class, you *must* initialize it in the initialization list, you cannot just assign it in your class's constructor body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can assigment cause the creation of some temporary object inside the constructor? That means that the Construtor would call itself: an infinite recursive call

No. The text talks about calling the constructor of the member. With an `int` it doesn't matter too much, but consider:

```
struct foo {
    foo() { 
        /* construct a foo, with expensive instructions */ 
        std::cout << "default constructor";
    }
    foo(int x) { 
        /* also construct a foo */ 
        std::cout << "constructor";
    }
};

struct bar_wrong {
    foo f;
    bar_wrong() { 
        f = foo(42);
    }
};
```

Members are initialized **before** the body of the constructor is executed. Hence the `foo` member of `bar_wrong` will first be default constructed (which is potentially expensive) just to be overwritten with the right instance later and creating a `bar_wrong` will print both outputs from `foo`s constructors.

The correct way is

```
struct bar_correct {
    foo f;
    bar_correct() : f(42) {}
};
```

Because here `foo` is only initialized. Alternatively you can use in-class initializers:

```
struct bar_alternative {
    foo f{42};
};
```

Here the compiler generated constructor is sufficient. It will use the in-class initializer to initialize `f` with `42`.

Comment: `foo f;` is only a declaration, it can't be causing the default construction, can it? Is there anyway I can verify the member has been initialized before the body of the constructor?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver, to construct `bar` you should first construct its data member, `foo`. *Is there any way...* - this is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Evg I believed constucting bar was assiging a value to its data members. So are u saying it can't be verified and I should just believe the standard?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver, no, constructing `bar` is constructing its data members first (you can't assign anything to an object that has not been constructed). But you can reassign them in the constructor body. You can verify it, e.g. by putting a few `std::cout`s.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver, [take a look](https://godbolt.org/z/ybxcJw).

Comment: Maybe also mention in-class initializers, as in `struct bar_correct {
    foo f{42};
    bar_correct() {}
};`

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver "Is there anyway I can verify the member has been initialized before the body of the constructor? " yes you can use my example and create a `bar_wrong`. The example is made to illustrate exactly that. You will see output from both `foo` constructors which hopefully convinces you that a `foo` is constructed before the body of the constructor is executed

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver sloppy speaking it isnt the `foo f;` declaration that calls `foo`s constructor, but the initialiaztaion of members that happens before you call the constructor